# postgre sql 9.4.5 won't start

Tags: ubuntu, psql

I can't start my newly install postgre which is 9.4.5. Please see error below.

> root@0f51e9aa2afc:/actinbox# service postgresql start  * Starting
>   PostgreSQL 9.4 database server
>   * The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output: LOG:  skipping missing configuration file
>   "/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.auto.conf" 2015-12-02
>   07:14:48 UTC [312-2] FATAL:  could not access private key file
>   "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key": Permission denied

Im using ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS on my daemon. Anyone who can help me?

Comment: Please skip the error missing configuration. Just the could not access private key file and psql won't start.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
sudo chown postgres /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
sudo chown postgres /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
```

If it doesn't work, try these:

```
(as root)
# go to PGDATA directory
cd /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main 
ls -l server.crt server.key

# confirm both of those files are symbolic links
# to files in /etc/ssl before going further

# remove symlinks to SSL certs
rm server.crt
rm server.key 

# copy the SSL certs to the local directory
cp /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem server.crt
cp /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key server.key

# set permissions on ssl certs
# and postgres ownership on everything else
# just in case
chown postgres *
chmod 640 server.crt server.key

service postgresql start
```

Comment: Already tried it. I'm getting the same error.                                                    The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2015-12-02 07:25:38 UTC [604-1] FATAL:  could not access private key file "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key": Permission denied

Comment: Thank you for your time But i've tried it already still getting the same error. Is there any way I can fix this?